# mysql все данные из 5 таблиц по условию

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

есть 5 таблиц:

1) games:

```
g_id | country | league | tour | team1 | team2 | и еще 10
```

2) events:

```
e_id | name | eTime | g_id |
```

3) Вообщем все имеют разное количество полей, я пытаю взять все данные (все поля) из всех 5 таблиц по условию, пример:

```
SELECT * FROM games 
  INNER JOIN events ON games.g_id = events.g_id 
  INNER JOIN stats ON games.g_id = stats.g_id
  INNER JOIN lineups ON games.g_id = lineups.g_id
  INNER JOIN ads ON games.g_id = ads.g_id
WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал'
```

В результате запрос в phpmyadmin виснет(на табличке пишет Загрузка... и все, висит). Пробовал этот же запрос с меньшим количеством таблиц с 2-3 данные загружались но тоже долго висит табличка "Загрузка", хотя после написано запрос занял 0.1 секунду. Простые запросы выполняются быстро (Select * from games)

Правильный ли это запрос, может можно как-то по другому взять все данные? Подскажите пожалуйста кому не тяжело...

Comment: сколько записей у вас на каждую игру в других таблицах? предполагаю, что не одна, в итоге получаете декартово произведение... если так, то надо пользоваться union, либо делать 4 запроса... **в общем**, приведите пример данных

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW all_tables AS SELECT * FROM games 
  INNER JOIN events ON games.g_id = events.g_id 
  INNER JOIN stats ON games.g_id = stats.g_id
  INNER JOIN lineups ON games.g_id = lineups.g_id
  INNER JOIN ads ON games.g_id = ads.g_id
```

Потом

```
SELECT * FROM all_tables WHERE team1 = 'Арсенал' LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Если phpmyadmin подвисает, пробуй делать запросы через терминал(консоль) если на локалке, задержка может быть в передаче инфы.

Comment: Представление тут врядли поможет, можно попробовать явно указать ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE, но есть сомнения.

Answer (score 0):

В связи с тем, что у вас в WHERE участвует только одна таблица, можно попробовать воспользоваться подзапросом, а затем JOIN-ить уже полученную выборку

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM games WHERE games.team1 = 'Арсенал') AS A
  INNER JOIN events ON A.g_id = events.g_id 
  INNER JOIN stats ON A.g_id = stats.g_id
  INNER JOIN lineups ON A.g_id = lineups.g_id
  INNER JOIN ads ON A.g_id = ads.g_id
WHERE A.team1 = 'Арсенал'
```

Но здесь проблема скорей с самим phpmyadmin-ом. Попробуйте через консоль, как уже и советовали выше.